# Is it really necessary to remove a term from the question title and replace it with a tag?

Tags: discussion, editing

I realize there is much discussion here regarding best practices for tagging, but is it really necessary to [remove a term such as 'Ubercart'](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/3888/revisions) from the question title, and replace it with a tag?

The question seems much clearer with 'Ubercart' in the title, and it immediately calls it out as not more general CCK issue.

Comment: The term was not replaced with a tag: the tag was already present in the question.